# When one enters and remains in cessation of perception and feeling during death where in 31 planes of existence will he go to?

Tags: theravada, nirvana, samsara, samadhi

The question is complete, no additional explanation of the question is needed. I just need the suttas.

For reference:

> “And further, with the complete transcending of the dimension of the
> infinitude of consciousness, (perceiving,) ‘There is nothing,’
> Sāriputta entered & remained in the **dimension of nothingness**.
> Whatever qualities there are in the dimension of nothingness—the
> perception of the dimension of nothingness, singleness of mind,
> contact, feeling, perception, intention, consciousness, desire,
> decision, persistence, mindfulness, equanimity, & attention—he
> ferreted them out one after another. Known to him they arose, known to
> him they became established, known to him they subsided. He discerned,
> ‘So this is how these qualities, not having been, come into play.
> Having been, they vanish.’ He remained unattracted & unrepelled with
> regard to those qualities, independent, detached, released,
> dissociated, with an awareness rid of barriers. He discerned that
> ‘**There is a further escape**,’ and pursuing it, he confirmed that
> ‘There is.’
>
> “And further, with the complete transcending of the dimension of
> nothingness, Sāriputta entered & remained in the **dimension of
> neither perception nor non-perception**. He emerged mindfully from
> that attainment. On emerging mindfully from that attainment, he
> regarded the past qualities that had ceased & changed: ‘So this is how
> these qualities, not having been, come into play. Having been, they
> vanish.’ He remained unattracted & unrepelled with regard to those
> qualities, independent, detached, released, dissociated, with an
> awareness rid of barriers. He discerned that ‘**There is a further
> escape**,’ and pursuing it, he confirmed that ‘There is.’
>
> “And further, with the complete transcending of the dimension of
> neither perception nor non-perception, Sāriputta entered & remained in
> the **cessation of perception & feeling**. And when he saw with
> discernment, his effluents were totally ended. He emerged mindfully
> from that attainment. On emerging mindfully from that attainment, he
> regarded the past qualities that had ceased & changed: ‘So this is how
> these qualities, not having been, come into play. Having been, they
> vanish.’ He remained unattracted & unrepelled with regard to those
> qualities, independent, detached, released, dissociated, with an
> awareness rid of barriers. He discerned that ‘**There is no further
> escape**,’ and pursuing it, he confirmed that ‘There isn’t.’
>
> https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN111.html

> “And I have also taught the step-by-step cessation of fabrications.
> When one has attained the first jhāna, speech has ceased. When one has
> attained the second jhāna, directed thought & evaluation have ceased.
> When one has attained the third jhāna, rapture has ceased. When one
> has attained the fourth jhāna, in-and-out breathing has ceased. When
> one has attained the dimension of the infinitude of space, the
> perception of forms has ceased. When one has attained the dimension of
> the infinitude of consciousness, the perception of the dimension of
> the infinitude of space has ceased. When one has attained the
> dimension of nothingness, the perception of the dimension of the
> infinitude of consciousness has ceased. When one has attained the
> dimension of neither-perception nor non-perception, the perception of
> the dimension of nothingness has ceased. When one has attained the
> **cessation of perception & feeling**, perception & feeling have ceased. When a monk’s effluents have ended, passion has ceased,
> aversion has ceased, delusion has ceased.
>
> [https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN36_11.html](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN111.html)

> “And this, monks, is the noble truth of the cessation of stress: the
> remainderless fading & cessation, renunciation, relinquishment,
> release, & **letting go of that very craving.**
>
> [https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN56_11.html](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN111.html)

> Now from the remainderless fading & cessation of that very ignorance
> comes the cessation of fabrications. From the cessation of
> fabrications comes the cessation of consciousness. From the cessation
> of consciousness comes the cessation of name-&-form. From the
> cessation of name-&-form comes the cessation of the six sense media.
> From the cessation of the six sense media comes the cessation of
> contact. From the cessation of contact comes the **cessation of
> feeling**. From the cessation of feeling comes the **cessation of
> craving**. From the cessation of craving comes the cessation of
> clinging/sustenance. From the cessation of clinging/sustenance comes
> the cessation of becoming. From the cessation of becoming comes the
> cessation of birth. From the cessation of birth, then aging-&-death,
> sorrow, lamentation, pain, distress, & despair all cease. Such is the
> cessation of this entire mass of stress & suffering.”
>
> [https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN12_15.html](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN111.html)

> Then there is the case where a monk, with the complete transcending of
> the dimension of the infinitude of consciousness, (perceiving,) ‘There
> is nothing,’ enters & remains in the dimension of nothingness. That is
> its transcending. But that, too, I tell you, isn’t enough. Abandon it,
> I tell you. Transcend it, I tell you. And what is its transcending?
>
> “Then there is the case where a monk, with the complete transcending
> of the dimension of nothingness, enters & remains in the **dimension
> of neither perception nor non-perception**. That is its transcending.
> But that, too, I tell you, isn’t enough. **Abandon it**, I tell you.
> Transcend it, I tell you. And what is its transcending?
>
> “There is the case where a monk, with the complete transcending of the
> **dimension of neither perception nor non-perception**, enters & remains in the **cessation of perception & feeling**. That is its
> transcending.
>
> “Thus, Udāyin, I speak even of the **abandoning** of the dimension of
> neither perception nor non-perception. Do you see any fetter, large or
> small, of whose abandoning I don’t speak?”
>
> “No, lord.”
>
> That is what the Blessed One said. Gratified, Ven. Udāyin delighted in
> the Blessed One’s words.
>
> [https://www.dharmatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN66.html](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN111.html)

> Then there is the case where a monk, with the complete transcending of
> the dimension of the infinitude of consciousness, (perceiving,) ‘There
> is nothing,’ enters & remains in the **dimension of nothingness**. If,
> as he remains there, he is beset with attention to perceptions dealing
> with the dimension of the infinitude of consciousness, **that is an
> affliction for him**.…
>
> “Then there is the case where a monk, with the complete transcending
> of the dimension of nothingness, enters & remains in the **dimension
> of neither perception nor non-perception**. If, as he remains there,
> he is beset with attention to perceptions dealing with the dimension
> of nothingness, **that is an affliction for him**. Now, the Blessed
> One has said that whatever is an affliction is stress. So by this line
> of reasoning it may be known how unbinding is pleasant.
>
> “Then there is the case where a monk, with the complete transcending
> of the dimension of neither perception nor non-perception, enters &
> remains in the **cessation of perception & feeling**. And as he sees
> (that) with discernment, effluents are completely ended. So by this
> line of reasoning it may be known how unbinding is pleasant.”
>
> [https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/AN/AN9_34.html](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN111.html)

> “Dependent on eye & forms, eye-consciousness arises. The meeting of
> the three is contact. With contact as a requisite condition, there is
> **feeling**. What one feels, one **perceives** [labels in the mind].
>
> [https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN18.html](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN111.html)

May all beings be happy and  liberated ❤️❤️
Metta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both is the top of  31 planes of existence. People there have longest life, however they are arising and vanishing more than trillion times per second as well, and they are going to die as well. They are not going to reborn in hell immediately, however they can reborn in hell the death after that reborn. **No where one can be hidden from death.**  Sutta Pitaka Vol 6 : Sutta. Ma. U. [Saṅkhārūpapattisuttaṃ](https://suttacentral.net/mn120/en/sujato).

> Furthermore, take a mendicant who has faith, ethics, learning, generosity, and wisdom. And they’ve heard: ‘The Radiant Gods … the Gods of Limited Radiance … the Gods of Limitless Radiance … the Gods of Streaming Radiance … the Gods of Limited Glory … the Gods of Limitless Glory … the Gods Replete with Glory … the Gods of Abundant Fruit … the Gods of Aviha … the Gods of Atappa … the Gods Fair to See … the Fair Seeing Gods … the Gods of Akaniṭṭha … the gods of the dimension of infinite space … the gods of the dimension of infinite consciousness … the gods of the dimension of nothingness … the gods of the dimension of neither perception nor non-perception are long-lived, beautiful, and very happy.’ They think: ‘If only, when my body breaks up, after death, I would be reborn in the company of the gods of the dimension of neither perception nor non-perception!’ They settle on that thought, stabilize it and develop it. Those choices and meditations of theirs, developed and cultivated like this, lead to rebirth there. This is the path and the practice that leads to rebirth there.

Comment: Yes this is the answer